# HTC vive development on Mac OS (Macbook Pro 15" late 2017 with Radeon pro 555)

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, htc-vive

G'day. 
As a new research project, I just started VR development with unity on mac machine.

I successfully developed with Gear VR but I am curious if I would be able to develop for HTC vive on my macbook pro.

It seems that SteamVR, which is development plugin for HTC vive, is now supported.

However, I'm not sure if my macbook GPU would be "sufficient" for Vive development.

Currently, my mac has 16GB RAM with Radeon pro 555.

Would this GPU sufficient? or would I be needing Windows machine with much higher GPU specs?

Unity program that I will be developing does not include complicated graphical randering : program that runs on Galaxy note 8 mounted Gear VR

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity's system requirements can be found on their website at https://unity3d.com/unity/system-requirements

For development:

> OS: Windows 7 SP1+, 8, 10, 64-bit versions only; macOS 10.11+
>
> Server versions of Windows & OS X are not tested. CPU: SSE2
>   instruction set support.
>
> GPU: Graphics card with DX10 (shader model 4.0) capabilities.
>
> **The rest mostly depends on the complexity of your projects.**

Additional platform development requirements:

> iOS: Mac computer running minimum macOS 10.12.6 and Xcode 9.0 or
>   higher. Android: Android SDK and Java Development Kit (JDK); IL2CPP
>   scripting backend requires Android NDK. Universal Windows Platform:
>   Windows 10 (64-bit), Visual Studio 2015 with C++ Tools component or
>   later and Windows 10 SDK

Comment: Thanks for the info.

I did, however developed simple unity VR project for Gear VR with my macbook.

I'm just not sure if I can run HTC vive with this machine for simple unity project.

Comment: for simple projects you probably could. Only way to find out is to try it out. As the section I put it bold implies.

Comment: I checked your graphic specs and I think it would struggle to run the Vive. Check out the link below on your graphic stats. https://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-Radeon-Pro-555-GPU-Benchmarks-and-Specs.226610.0.html

Comment: ya, only 2gb video memory could prove difficult, just don't expend a lot of resources on scenery and it should be fine

Comment: according to this, it has thunderbolt 3? if thats true, then you can get an external gpu to power the development https://support.apple.com/kb/SP756?locale=en_US

Comment: Thanks @cecilmerrelakabringrainfire ! All I need for my projects are several boxes or cubes that "looks like" fridge or door and their interaction with vive. If I find this demanding, I should definitely consider eGPU!